# Breaking out of a recursive function

Tags: recursion, rebol, rebol3, rebol2, red

I'm walking through a set of nested blocks and want to stop the walk when I've found the value I'm looking for.

For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, I can't use PARSE for this particular problem, nor use FOREACH as the looper:

```
walk: func [series [block!] criteria [block!]][
    use [value] compose/deep [
        while [not tail? series][
            value: pick series 1

            either block? value [
                walk value criteria
            ][
                (to paren! criteria)
            ]

            series: next series
        ]
    ]
]
```

I'd like to break out if I find this specific value.

```
walk [a [b c [d e] f] g] [if value = 'e [return value]]
; returns 'e
```

However, I'd also like to do operations that don't break out:

```
walk [a [b c [d e] f] g] [
    collect [if find [c e] value [keep value]]
]
; returns [c e]
```

Would like to try and solve this for any of the Rebol flavours including Red. Any thoughts as to efficiency (reason I use a block instead of a function), etc. would be welcome too.

Comment: **`use`** prevents me from running this code inside *Red*. Would using `/local` in the *func spec* still work with your code?

Comment: FYI, with Rebol2 and Ren-c (the rebol flavours I tried) it either gives an error or returns empty block. So I assume you want an empty block when it fails?

Comment: @GeekyI Not quite—COMPOSE/DEEP builds a new block that USE then binds to it's generated context. This happens in every invocation so in addition to adding `/local node` you need to bind the COMPOSE block to `'node` (see [here](https://github.com/rgchris/Scripts/blob/master/experimental/altxml.red#L184)). And at that, there's a downside in that you are also binding the words `series` and `criteria` which would override the context of those words if they were in the calling block. e.g. `walk [some data][series: 'foo]`

Comment: Used `node` where I'd meant `value` in the above comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function combo I was looking for is CATCH/THROW. Once again, using the given function:

```
walk: func [series [block!] criteria [block!]][
    use [value] compose/deep [
        while [not tail? series][
            value: pick series 1

            either block? value [
                walk value criteria
            ][
                (to paren! criteria)
            ]

            series: next series
        ]
    ]
]
```

I can simply wrap it as follows:

```
catch [walk [a [b c [d e] f] g] [if value = 'e [throw value]]]
; returns 'e
```

### Some Notes

- I want the function to return NONE if there are no matches

I'll just have WALK return NONE (am using ALSO just so as not to leave an awkward trailing `none`):

```
 walk: func [series [block!] criteria [block!]][
      also none use [value] compose/deep [
          while [not tail? series][
              value: pick series 1

              either block? value [
                  walk value criteria
              ][
                  (to paren! criteria)
              ]

              series: next series
          ]
      ]
  ]
```

- [red](/questions/tagged/red) does not have a USE function

This introduces a complication as I *only* want to bind the block to the word VALUE. If I were to rewrite the function as follows:

```
walk: func [series [block!] criteria [block!] /local value][
    do bind compose/deep [
        while [not tail? series][
            value: pick series 1

            either block? value [
                walk value criteria
            ][
                (to paren! criteria)
            ]

            series: next series
        ]
    ] 'value
]
```

Then it also binds that same block to the words SERIES and CRITERIA which would override the binding of any such words from the calling context, e.g.:

```
walk [some values][series: none probe value] ; results in error
```

Answer (score 2):

This version avoids binding anything except VALUE and works in Red 0.6.3 and Rebol2:

```
walk: func [series [block!] criteria [block!]][
    also none do bind compose/deep [
        while [not tail? series] [
            value: pick series 1
            either block? value [
                walk value criteria
            ] [
                (to paren! criteria)
            ]
            series: next series
        ]
    ]
    context [value: none]
]
```

(Comments on how this implementation differs from what USE does would be welcome.)

And yes, this does not work on Rebol3 Alpha. But neither does the one with the USE. I think it's a THROW issue.